# How to get user's information by using TikTok SDK Login?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, sdk, userinfo

I am using TikTok SDK login from TikTok for developers portal. https://developers.tiktok.com in my mobile app. (We have registered and got the client_id and client_secret)

I am able to authenticate user from the SDK, but no user information is coming back from TikTok like username,firstname,unique_id,followers_count etc.

We can share the video directly to tiktok using SDK, but there is no user information available.

There is no much information available from TikTok on there Developer portal, Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: There are no much updates from Tiktok developers on this. But you can check this link https://github.com/szdc/tiktok-api. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's intentional, but it doesn't seem like Tik Tok has a very high priority on creating a robust API. Their IOS sdk seems to only have the ability to share videos to their platform, but not much else.

This repo may offer something for you ([github.com/szdc/tiktok-api](http://github.com/szdc/tiktok-api)) but the documentation isn't very clear.

Tik Tok also doesn't have a very good web version, which is a smart move if they're trying to protect their data from devs like us who are trying to build on top of their platform.